# How to reference a whole library in Latex using different directory?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, miktex

I have been trying to use a whole library and then use the in-text citation method to compile a reference section.  I am getting stuck when I try to reference the whole library which is in a different directory than my latex file (I want this to stay this way, I am not looking for a solution in the same directory, if possible).

Thus far I have the following:

```
\bibliographystyle{aea}
\bibliography{/Users/username/OneDrive/Documents/Bibtex/library}
```

Within the Bibtex folder there is a library.bib file stored, which contains my citation (I have verified this).  However, when I run my bibtex in Latex the following error is displayed:

"This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary         file: Final paper.aux The style file: aea.bst I couldn't open database file C:/Users/Joachim/OneDrive/Documents/Bibtex/library.bib.bib ---line 4 of file Final paper.aux : \bibdata{C:/Users/Joachim/OneDrive/Documents/Bibtex/library.bib : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no database files---while reading file Final paper.aux Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "BDM1964" (There were 2 error messages)"

The file is saved as "library.bib" in the Bibtex folder.  Any advice would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: additionally, I want to note that the code is before `\end{document}` and after all my text

Comment: Have you tried to  replace `/Users/username/OneDrive/Documents/Bibtex/library` with `C:/Users/Joachim/OneDrive/Documents/Bibtex/library.bib`

Comment: This worked, even though I tried it earlier.  I think I had to run the quick build twice to get it to work properly however, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path `/Users/username/OneDrive/Documents/Bibtex/library` is not recognised as a DOS/Windows path. One should use `C:/Users/Joachim/OneDrive/Documents/Bibtex/library` instead.